# PHP fputcsv causing err_invalid_response error

Tags: php, cakephp, fputcsv

The function that generates a CSV is as follows:

**Main csv output function:**

```
function admin_getOscrReport(){
        $oscr = $this->Oscr->find('all');
        $headers = array("Charity ID", "Charity Name", "Registered Date", "Known As", "Charity Status", "Postcode", "Constitutional Form", "Previous Constitutional Form",
            "Geographical Spread", "Operations Location", "Purposes", "Beneficiaries", "Activities", "Objectives", "Address", "Website", "Recent Year Income",
            "Recent Year Expenditure", "Mail Cycle", "Year End", "Parent Charity Name", "Parent Charity Number", "Parent Charity Country Reg", "Religious Body", "Regulatory Type");
        $this->set('oscrs', $oscr);
        $this->layout = null;
        $this->autoLayout = false;
        Configure::write('debug','0');

        $filename = "oscr_reporting.csv";
        header("Content-type: text/csv");

        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
        header("Pragma: no-cache");
        header("Expires: 0");

        $data = fopen('php://output', 'w');

        fputcsv($data,$headers);

        foreach($oscr as $row){
            foreach($row as $r){
                fputcsv($data,$r);
            }
        }
        fclose($data);
    }
```

This outputs the correct csv file on a ***local wamp server*** but not on a similar test server environment. Have tried on multiple browsers, and same issue.

getting a "**ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE**"

**USING CAKEPHP1.3**

Any ideas on a fix or why this is happening would be great!

Answer (score 0):

please check if `mod_sec` on your server is flagging the request as an attempt of a file injection attack and returns a 403 forbidden response wrongly displayed as a `ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE`.